# Menu disappearing in UV Edit mode

Tags: uv

[image: The menu on the right disappears when I go into UV Edit. Can anyone advise how to get it back please?]

The menu on the right disappears when I go into UV Edit.  Can anyone advise how to get it back please?

Answer (score 0):

1 Go to View >> Area >> Vertical split then Editor Type >> Outliner

2 Go to View >> Area >> Horizontal Split Then Editor Type >> Properties

[image]

Hope that helps

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked a treat.

Also, Shift + F7 while your mouse is over the section will change to the properties window.